# TypeScript narrowing triggered by assigning reference

Tags: typescript, narrowing, type-narrowing

I've run across a behavior in TypeScript that I think should be legal, but isn't. Take a look at the following code snippet.

```
type One = { id: string };
type Two = { id: string, displayOrder: number };

let oneVal: One = { id: 'dogs' };
let twoVal: Two = { id: 'cats', displayOrder: 2 };

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let val: One | Two = oneVal;

  // val.displayOrder - error TS2339: Property 'displayOrder' does not exist on type 'never'.
  if ('displayOrder' in val && val.displayOrder === 2) {
    console.log("This isn't allowed to run.");
  }

  val = twoVal;
}
```

What's happening here is, when I assign `oneVal` to `val`, TypeScript immediately narrows `val` to type One. Then `'displayOrder' in val` narrows val to never.

The narrowing from `One | Two` to `One` could be justified if I didn't have the for loop, but I do. And the issue only happens if I assign a reference. The issue doesn't occur if I assign an object literal to val.

```
val = { id: 'dogs' }; // Does not trigger narrowing, which makes sense.
```

If anyone has any feedback or disagreements, please raise them here.

Comment: I don't get it; you are setting `val` to `oneVal` at the beginning of every iteration of loop, why should the loop affect anything about the narrowing here? Is this a typo?

Comment: `val = {id: "dogs"}` does not trigger narrowing?  [Yes it does](https://tsplay.dev/mMx8rN).  I am confused.

Comment: Sorry, @jcalz, you're correct. The issue still happens however if I move val outside of the loop. Let me revise, I wrote the snippet rather quickly.

Comment: Dang it, I was wrong. Will comment, thanks all for the speedy reply. User error

Answer (score 0):

@jcalz got me. I placed `val` within the for loop, so val is unambiguously `One`. This was user error. Once I moved `val` outside of the for loop, the TS error disappeared.